# Show that $y(x) = xa^{2x}\exp(x^2)$ has no stationary points for $e^{−\sqrt{2}} <a< e^{\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: calculus

Show that $y(x) = xa^{2x}\exp(x^2)$ has no stationary points other than $x = 0$, if
$e^{−\sqrt{2}} <a< e^{\sqrt{2}}$.

I've reduced the equation for $y'$ to $2x^2 + 2x\ln a + 1$
but I'm clueless on how to solve it after...

Comment: You can use latex to formatting the equation!

Comment: Presumably you have actually looked at $y'/y$, which has a problem when $x=0$

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$y'(x)=(2x^2+2x\ln a+1)a^{2x}\exp(x^2)$$

Thus $y'(x)=0$ if and only if:

$$2x^2+2x\ln a+1=0\qquad \text{or} \qquad a^{2x}=0\qquad \text{or} \qquad \exp(x^2)=0.$$

Clearly the last condition is not possible. The second condition requires that $a=0$, but such an $a$ is less than $\exp\left(-\sqrt(2)\right)$

So, since $a\neq 0$, the first condition must hold, i.e. the stationary point must satisfy

$$2x^2+2x\ln a+1=0.$$

This equation is not satisfied when $x=0$. So, the thing you want to prove is not correct.  To solve the quadratic above you can just apply the quadratic formula. You will get two (nonzero) solutions. The bounds on $a$ ensure that neither of them are real. Thus there is no stationary point when $a\neq 0$.

---

Perhaps you actually wanted to show that $y(x) = xa^{2x}\exp(x^2)$ has no stationary points unless $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{1}$, if $\exp(−\sqrt{2}) <a< \exp(\sqrt{2})$? Or is there an error in your definition of the function $y$?